# Let N = Fit(G). Why $ N = O_{p}(G) $ and $ A \leq Z(N) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a soluble group and $ A $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $,where $ A $ is an elementary abelian group of prime power order. Let each chief factor of $ G/A $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime and $ A $ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $.  let $ \vert A \vert = p^{\alpha} $, then $ \vert A \vert > p $ if $ p > 2 $ and $ \vert A \vert > 4 $ if $ p = 2 $. Let N = Fit(G). Why $ N = O_{p}(G) $ and $ A \leq Z(N) $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N \ne O_p(G)$ then some prime $q \ne p$ divides $|N|$ and then $O_q(N)=O_q(G) \ne 1$ contradicting the fact that $A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Note that $A \cap Z(N)$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $A$ and, since $A$ is a minimal normal subgroup, we must have $A \cap Z(N)=A$ so $A \le Z(N)$.

Comment: Let $ F/N = O_{p^{\prime}}(G/N) $. Why $ F > N $?

Comment: Since $N=O_p(G)$, $O_p(G/N)=1$ and so $O_{p'}(G/N) \ne 1$.

Comment: Since $ G $ is soluble, then $ O_{p}(G/N) = 1 $ ?

Comment: No, $O_p(G/N)=1$ because $N=O_p(G)$. I said that before!

Comment: I have another question.$ (\vert N \vert , \vert F/N \vert) = $ ? If $ (\vert N \vert , \vert F/N \vert) = 1 $ then by Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, there exists a subgroup $ V \leq F $ such that $ F = VN $ and $ V \cap N = 1 $. Why $ V \in Syl_{p}(N) $ ?

Comment: Please ask a new question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26182/discussion-between-soroush-and-derek-holt).